# PHP Upload HTML file

Tags: php, html

i want to upload a html file to the server via upload script.

when i tried to upload html file it is saying invalid file. but the other formats given below are working.

```
$allowedExts = array("html", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")

|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")

|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")

|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")

|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")

|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000000)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: check for type text/html ;)

Comment: thank u, it is working now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `$allowedExts` is not used?!

You can check the mime-type for html:

```
<?php

$allowedMimeTypes = explode(',', 'image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,text/html'); // add more mime-types if needed

if (in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $allowedMimeTypes) && $_FILES['file']['size'] < 200000000) {
    /** ok do something **/
}

else {
    /** Oooops error **/
}
```

Comment: thank u, i have already got anwer from the above comment. but your answer also very useful.